# Why use optimistic concurrency and advisory locks together

Tags: postgresql

I am a PostgreSQL newbie.

I have the following `write_message` function from the [Message Store database of Eventide project](https://github.com/message-db/message-db/blob/master/database/functions/write-message.sql).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION write_message(
  id varchar,
  stream_name varchar,
  "type" varchar,
  data jsonb,
  metadata jsonb DEFAULT NULL,
  expected_version bigint DEFAULT NULL
)
RETURNS bigint
AS $$
DECLARE
  _message_id uuid;
  _stream_version bigint;
  _next_position bigint;
BEGIN
  PERFORM acquire_lock(write_message.stream_name);

  _stream_version := stream_version(write_message.stream_name);

  IF _stream_version IS NULL THEN
    _stream_version := -1;
  END IF;

  IF write_message.expected_version IS NOT NULL THEN
    IF write_message.expected_version != _stream_version THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION
        'Wrong expected version: % (Stream: %, Stream Version: %)',
        write_message.expected_version,
        write_message.stream_name,
        _stream_version;
    END IF;
  END IF;

  _next_position := _stream_version + 1;

  _message_id = uuid(write_message.id);

  INSERT INTO messages
    (
      id,
      stream_name,
      position,
      type,
      data,
      metadata
    )
  VALUES
    (
      _message_id,
      write_message.stream_name,
      _next_position,
      write_message.type,
      write_message.data,
      write_message.metadata
    )
  ;

  IF current_setting('debug_write', true) = 'on' OR current_setting('debug', true) = 'on' THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '» write_message';
    RAISE NOTICE 'id ($1): %', write_message.id;
    RAISE NOTICE 'stream_name ($2): %', write_message.stream_name;
    RAISE NOTICE 'type ($3): %', write_message.type;
    RAISE NOTICE 'data ($4): %', write_message.data;
    RAISE NOTICE 'metadata ($5): %', write_message.metadata;
    RAISE NOTICE 'expected_version ($6): %', write_message.expected_version;
    RAISE NOTICE '_stream_version: %', _stream_version;
    RAISE NOTICE '_next_position: %', _next_position;
  END IF;

  RETURN _next_position;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE;
```

It uses advisory lock on the value of parameter `write_message.stream_name`.

However, it also implements optimistic concurrency on `stream_version(write_message.stream_name)` which is basically `max(position) from messages` where `stream_name` is same as argument `stream_version` that was passed in to the function (see function definition for `stream_version` below).

`position` is an incrementing integer indicating the position/ordinal of a rown among all rows with the same `stream_name`.

Thus if another message had been written to the `messages` table with the same `stream_name` since the function started executing, then the passed in `steam_version` argument would be smaller than the now current `max(position)`

**My question is:** what is the reason for using both advisory lock on `stream_name` (this seems to be like an OS-provided semaphore, like critical section or mutex in Windows or `Monitor.Enter` in .NET) as well as optimistic locking essentially on the same thing?

Function `acquire_lock` is as follows (just acquires an advisory lock as far as I can see):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION acquire_lock(
  stream_name varchar
)
RETURNS bigint
AS $$
DECLARE
  _category varchar;
  _category_name_hash bigint;
BEGIN
  _category := category(acquire_lock.stream_name);
  _category_name_hash := hash_64(_category);
  PERFORM pg_advisory_xact_lock(_category_name_hash);

  IF current_setting('debug_write', true) = 'on' OR current_setting('debug', true) = 'on' THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '» acquire_lock';
    RAISE NOTICE 'stream_name: %', acquire_lock.stream_name;
    RAISE NOTICE '_category: %', _category;
    RAISE NOTICE '_category_name_hash: %', _category_name_hash;
  END IF;

  RETURN _category_name_hash;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE;
```

`stream_version` function is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION message_store.stream_version(
  stream_name varchar
)
RETURNS bigint
AS $$
DECLARE
  _stream_version bigint;
BEGIN
  SELECT
    max(position) into _stream_version
  FROM
    messages
  WHERE
    messages.stream_name = stream_version.stream_name;

  RETURN _stream_version;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE;
```

Thanks a lot!

I tried posting a message here.

Comment: Looks like they don't want the function to run simultaneously in two database sessions for the same `stream_name`. The reason for that is not explained.

Comment: Note that these are not the same, as one operates on the stream name and the other on the category of the stream name.  I don't know what the significance of that is, but perhaps there is some.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. @jjanes well done for spotting that advisory lock on category of stream_name (a prefix of stream_name) rather than on stream_name itself. In fact what is odd is that: advisory lock is on hash of the category which seems completely unnecessary to me, as does locking on prefix of stream_name (coarser-grained lock than necessary) rather than on stream_name itself. I think the reason why they are using both locks is because the optimistic locking check is outside of (before) the INSERT statement. In SQL Server I would have wrapped the whole thing in BEGIN/END TRAN.

Comment: ..with a transaction isolation level of SERIALIZABLE of course

Comment: It could be that the optimistic assumption was being violated too often in this one location, leading to excess retries and performance problems.  Bolting an advisory lock on afterward would be a lot easier than ripping out the optimistic model and redoing it.  I tried to reviewing the git commit messages around the change, but they didn't seem very informative.

Comment: I think you're right @jjanes. If I understand you correctly (a big if, as I've only been using PG for a few days so please do correct me if I'm wrong): if they had wrapped the whole thing in BEGIN TRAN and END TRAN then because of Postgres's default of MVCC, they might have been getting too many optimistic concurrency failures in this location and the use of an advisory lock alleviates that. I must say PG's advisory locks provide superb granularity compared with SQL Server's transactions with automatic locking of rows (potentially entire tables).

Comment: or maybe they've used advisory locks to ensure that the simple operation of inserting a record into the `messages` table (with optimistic concurrency check) never needs a retry and will always succeed